# I'm trying to create a SPA based React website with Vite, but nothing is rendering, the page just shows a blank page. How can I fix my vite config?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

As the title states, I'm currently trying to create a react website with the use of Vite, but for some reason no matter what I do or try, nothing renders on the page. I've tried removing the use of react-router-dom and directly render the Home file, but no luck. Does anyone have any ideas? It seems to render the index.html just fine, but doesn't render my jsx files.

./src/app.jsx

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { HashRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../index.css';
import Home from './Pages/Homepage/homepage.jsx';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter>
      <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

./src/Pages/Homepage/homepage.jsx
import React from 'react';
import valentinesGif from '../../../Dependencies/saintvalentineday.gif';
import './homepage.css';

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="home-container">
      <img src={valentinesGif} alt="Valentine's Day" className="centered-gif" />
      <div className="button-container">
        <button>Button 1</button>
        <button>Button 2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;

vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { resolve } from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  server: {
    strictPort: true,
    port: 8888,
    open: true,
  },
});

index.html (root)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testing</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6483512793.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't import the `app.jsx` file in the `index.html` file, import it with a script tag. e.g:

```html
<script type="module" src="/src/app.jsx"></script>
```

Comment: you're right, I totally missed that. Thank you so much!